# How can I avoid generating PDB files for .Net nuget packages?

Tags: nuget-package, cefsharp, pdb

I'am using CefSharp assemblies in my project c# project as references. Even after I set Debugging information to 'None' in the Advanced Build Settings dialog, I'm getting PDB files being generated in the output folder for all CefSharp related files.

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway to stop generating them in my output folder.

Comment: The term `generating` makes it sound like you are building the project from source, which according to your other comment below you are actually just using the `nuget` packages, please edit you question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The `CefSharp` nuget packages include the pdb files deliberately. The decision to include them predates Nuget.org being capable of hosting snupkg files and before embedding symbols in the dlls existed. For Open Source projects it's very important to have easy access to symbols for meaningful stack traces.

You can exclude the pdb (and xml) files from your build output using a `target` in your `proj` file. The following should exclude `pdb` and `xml` files. Noting the extension only checks file extension, you can easily adapt this to meet your own specific requirements.

```xml
<Target Name="ExcludePdbFilesAfterCompile" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_FilteredContentWithTargetPath Include="@(ContentWithTargetPath)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.pdb'" />
      <_FilteredContentWithTargetPath Include="@(ContentWithTargetPath)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.xml'" />
      <ContentWithTargetPath Remove="@(_FilteredContentWithTargetPath)" />

      <_FilteredReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.pdb'" />
      <_FilteredReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.xml'" />
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(_FilteredReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about cefsharp but for visual studio i create nuget package like this.

[image]

Then upload this package to nuget. That's all I do. Hope this helps you to find the solution, at least creates a spark.

Comment: Actually I'm a user of the nuget package and not a creator.

Comment: So, maybe the creator pre-releasing the package as a debug build. Or the creator doesn't aware of the .pdb files.

Comment: If the `CefSharp Nuget` packages came from `Nuget.org` then it's a release build and the `pdb` files are included deliberately, the decision to include them predates `Nuget.org` being capable of hosting `snupkg` files and before embedding symbols in the dlls existed. For `Open Source` projects it's very important to have easy access to symbols for meaningful stack traces. You can exclude the `pdb` files from your build output using target(s).